# Exception when using properties StrokeColor or StrokeThickness in a MapControl MapPolyLine

Tags: xaml, uwp, xamlparseexception

I am developing a Universal Windows 10 application that will use maps control. In a view I have something like this:

```
<maps:MapControl Grid.Column="1" MapServiceToken="...">
    <maps:MapPolyline StrokeColor="Navy" StrokeThickness="2" 
                      Path="{Binding LineRoute.DirectionAStreetVertices, 
                        Converter={StaticResource LineRouteEntryEnumerableToGeoPathConverter}}" />
</maps:MapControl>
```

When I build the application successfully and reach that page, I receive a XamlParseException, with a message like "
Cannot deserialize XBF metadata property list as 'StrokeColor' was not found in type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapPolyline'. [Line: 0 Position: 0]"

If I remove the StrokeColor and StrokeThickness, there isn't any error, but I won't see any polyline at all, of course.

Comment: Does it also crash if you add the MapPolyline via code instead of XAML?

Comment: Interesting approach!!!. I have done so. And it does work. Well, not with the binding... yet, but with a static path. Have to check how to set the binding to see if it works

Comment: Well, according to this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn792121.aspx, it looks like it doesn't work with XAML. Welcome to the pre-XAML age!!!, I have done with behaviors, that create the polyline. But writing in the code behind is a no-go.

Comment: Yeah I also tried to find a page which says so... there were WP8 MSDN pages, which stated that this was not possible on WP8(.1) but in WP8 times the XAML editor already complained when writing such code. The map runs somewhere out of XAML, that's why this is not possible I guess. Also, for WP8.1, WP8 and Windows 8 there was this great nuget package: http://wpwinnl.codeplex.com/ but it's not (yet?) available for Win 10.